# How to integrate google analytics in django admin panel?

Tags: django, google-analytics, django-admin

I m a newbie to django admin.I wanted to integrate Google Analytics to my admin panel so that I could see all the graphs and analytics data in my admin dashboard itself.I have registered with  https://analytics.google.com/analytics and got all the necessary id's like tracking id and all .  Can somebody guide me getting this thing done ..

Thanks in advance

Comment: See  [Analytics Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/). Then, override the admin templates.

Comment: "Guiding how it's done" is not really what happens on SO as far as I have observed - you are expected to try something and ask when you hit specific problems.

Comment: Yes,that is true but this is one of the issues that does not have any support over google or other .